# Excel count minimum required to reach total of consecutive cells

Tags: excel, sum, offset

I have a set of data (see below) with a formula that tells me the minimum number of consecutive entries required to sum to a total:

```
Date        Deliveries   FORMULA
2/11/1998   132.75       47
3/11/1998   170.65       46
4/11/1998   439.55       45
5/11/1998   457.85       45
6/11/1998   337.75       44
9/11/1998   760.2        43
10/11/1998  544.75       42
11/11/1998  28.1         41
12/11/1998  27.95        40
13/11/1998  124.25       39
16/11/1998  826.2        38
17/11/1998  1350.15      37
18/11/1998  1624.3       37
19/11/1998  2076.9       37
```

Please note the data in column A and B continue for another 200 + Rows.

The formula in C5 is:

```
  =MATCH($D$3,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B5,,,ROW(B5:B262)-ROW(B5))),1)
```

I drag this down in col C and find the minimum which is 37 - basically the minimum number of deliveries to reach my total in D3.

What I want to know is how can I make this so I don't have to drag the formula down, Ie the result is 37 and confirmed by a single entry rather than finding the minimum of Col C.

Cheers!

Comment: Here are two ideas. First, don't drag - click. Select C5 and Copy. Click "Find & Select -> GoTo". In the Reference field enter C6:C262. Press OK to select the target range. Press Enter to complete the paste process. Second, let us know what is in D3 :-)

Comment: I think you missed the boat here. Drag was a concept, I would like to be able to perform the analysis in one cell rather than need a helper column. 

I am sure there is an array formula that could achieve the same result, but I just can't figure out how. 

The contents of D3 really aren't super important, it is just a target. But for completeness it is 80% of the total sum of the deliveries.